# Volume created in dockerfile isn't mounted in the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to lock firefox in a docker container. To do so, I created the following `dockerfile` file:

```
FROM debian:sid

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    firefox \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd \
      --create-home \
      --home-dir /home/morfitest/ \
      --shell /bin/bash \
      --uid 1000 \
      --user-group \
      morfitest

USER morfitest

ENV HOME /home/morfitest

RUN mkdir /home/morfitest/.mozilla
VOLUME ["/home/morfitest/.mozilla"]

WORKDIR /home/morfitest/

CMD /usr/bin/firefox
```

I also have a `docker-compose.yml` file, which looks like this:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
   browser:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: dockerfile
     image: firefox:morfitest
     container_name: firefox
     hostname: firefox
     domainname: local
     restart: "no"
     volumes:
#       - user_profile:/home/morfitest/.mozilla/
       - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
     environment:
       - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
     logging:
       driver: syslog
       options:
         syslog-address: "tcp://192.168.43.247:514"
         tag: "firefox-morfitest"
     networks:
       default:
         ipv4_address: 10.10.2.10

#volumes:
#    user_profile:

networks:
  default:
    name: firefox
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.2.0/24
```

I've read that when you want to start a container as a non-root user, you can't use `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file because it can't handle the dir permissions in the right way when it mounts the volume using `bind` . So the volume has to be specified in the `dockerfile` file using:

```
USER morfitest
RUN mkdir /home/morfitest/.mozilla
VOLUME ["/home/morfitest/.mozilla"]
```

The container builds and works fine, but I can't really figure out why the volume can't be mounted when the container boots/starts.

When I inspect the container, I can see the following:

```
$ docker container inspect firefox | grep vol
                "Type": "volume",
                "Source": "/media/Zami/docker/volumes/f2a4ee3dd34e2711b262f104e6b1aea6c07d107c38ec837c2baf11a39227c754/_data",


# ls -al /media/Zami/docker/volumes/f2a4ee3dd34e2711b262f104e6b1aea6c07d107c38ec837c2baf11a39227c754/_data
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 morfik morfik 4096 2019-01-21 09:30:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 2019-01-21 09:30:55 ../
drwx------ 2 morfik morfik 4096 2019-01-21 09:30:57 extensions/
drwx------ 5 morfik morfik 4096 2019-01-21 09:30:57 firefox/
drwx------ 2 morfik morfik 4096 2019-01-21 09:30:57 systemextensionsdev/
```

So the volume exists and has some content, but it doesn't work. When I used the following `CMD` in the `dockerfile` file:

```
CMD  ls -al /home/morfitest/ &&  ls -al /home/morfitest/.mozilla
```

to actually see whether the content of the volume is visible when the container boots/starts, I could only see this:

```
firefox-morfitest[61138]: total 24
firefox-morfitest[61138]: drwxr-xr-x 1 morfitest morfitest 4096 Jan 21 08:05 .
firefox-morfitest[61138]: drwxr-xr-x 1 root      root      4096 Jan 21 08:05 ..
firefox-morfitest[61138]: -rw-r--r-- 1 morfitest morfitest  220 Jun 17  2018 .bash_logout
firefox-morfitest[61138]: -rw-r--r-- 1 morfitest morfitest 3526 Jun 17  2018 .bashrc
firefox-morfitest[61138]: drwxr-xr-x 2 morfitest morfitest 4096 Jan 21 08:05 .mozilla
firefox-morfitest[61138]: -rw-r--r-- 1 morfitest morfitest  807 Jun 17  2018 .profile

firefox-morfitest[61138]: total 8
firefox-morfitest[61138]: drwxr-xr-x 2 morfitest morfitest 4096 Jan 21 08:05 .
firefox-morfitest[61138]: drwxr-xr-x 1 morfitest morfitest 4096 Jan 21 08:05 ..
```

The dir `.mozilla` has the right permissions, but it's empty. So how to mount the volume?

Comment: right I missed that. Just to make sure I understand your question, you want to mount a directory on the host to the container? under volumes section, does `/path/on/host:/path/container` work?

Comment: Yes, I want do that. It works fine when run as root, but I start firefox as a regular user and I need the volume to be accessed by non-root. And I can't use the `docker-compose.yml` file for this. I have to use `dockerfile` -- at least I've read so.

Comment: I tried your config and it worked. I think your container was mounting a previous volume (which is empty), try `docker volume prune` or/and `docker system prune`.

Comment: Check what happens when you type `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` . Do your FF rememeber the last session?

Comment: it remembers my browsing history

Comment: When I start the container using `docker-compose up` and close the browser, and then again type `docker-compose up`, then it works fine. But when I close the browser and type `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up`, for some reason it doesn't remember anything -- it looks like the volume isn't accessed. But when I close the browser and again start it via  `docker-compose up`, it shows me what was in the session before. So what's wrong with it? Only first `docker-compose up` fails to mount the volume? Maybe it mounts it "on demand" or something? Could you check that?

Comment: I did not have any permission issue with the volume section, I mean that they are not commented out.

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the config files are OK, the problem was in the lines that were commented out. Actually the hashes should be removed and the setup works fine.

But when I tried to do that at the beginning, the volume was ignored -- some parts of the following warning weren't displayed because of some visual bug:

```
WARNING: Service "browser" is using volume "/home/morfitest/.mozilla" from the
previous container. Host mapping "docker-firefox_user_profile" has no effect.
Remove the existing containers (with docker-compose rm browser)
```

I removed the container as it wanted, and now, it creates a volume with a persistent name: `docker-firefox_user_profile` instead of a hash. Now when I do `down`/`up` it uses the volume instead of creating a new one. And this solves my problem.